# How can Python get the path to a directory of images when packaging a script?

Tags: python, package

Here is my script:

```
current_directory=os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
self.image_array = glob.glob(os.path.join(current_directory,"./data/world_flag_game/flags/*.png")
```

This works fine when I run it (using quickly) from the terminal but when I package it (using quickly package) it seems that the path is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the path is not working, it probably isn't the path where the .png images are located. Try printing the path from the terminal as well as from your packaged application. Something like the following will help you to see why the images are not found.

```
print("%r" % current_directory)
```

It's not surprising that the application's build directory would be different than its development directory. So you may want to replace your `os.path.join(...)` with an absolute directory to verify that your application works when packaged. Then it's a matter of storing your images into the build directory and then pointing to that location correctly.

Comment: I want to publish to ubuntu software center the app what path i should use to store my images, in a way that there will be no problem with every ubuntu user that installs my app.

Comment: Have you read through [these guidelines](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/)?